# Change date format in code only

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I've a code that simply creates a folder in a directory and gives it a name based on the values of a datetimepicker and a text box.

The date picker is displayed on the form as "16 October 2013" (how I want to keep it) but when I generate the file name I would lime the date to read in the format "161013"

The code I'm using is below if that helps

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)    Handles Button1.Click

    Dim lMailbox As String


    lMailbox = t2.Text & "-" & d1.Text

    ' Check if folder exists, if not: create it
    If Not Directory.Exists(nMailbox & lMailbox) Then
        Directory.CreateDirectory(nMailbox & lMailbox)

        ' Folder created message
        MessageBox.Show("Mailbox created!", "Lynx Control Panel", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
    Else
        ' Folder already exists
        MessageBox.Show("Mailbox already exists!", "Lynx Control Panel", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop)
    End If
End Sub
```

The nMailbox & lMailbox are declared at the top of the code page

d1 is the name of the datepicker

I'm very new to VB.net and would appreciate any help

Thanks

Comment: For combining paths, you might want to consider [IO.Path.Combine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine.aspx) - it takes care of fiddly things likes path separators for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
lMailbox = t2.Text & "-" & d1.Value.ToString("ddMMyy")
```

The [format options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.customformat.aspx) are the same as for DateTime string formatting.  Use `Value` of the DTP rather than the `Text` which is formatted otherwise/

Comment: I think you might have meant `lMailbox = t2.Text & "-" & d1.Value.ToString("ddMMyy")`.

Comment: Yes, I did not notice he was using `Text`, but you want MMMM for the month name

Comment: OP wants the directory name to end with, e.g. "161013" - your first (second? ;) ) go was correct.

Comment: Thanks so much both of you - works a treat. Andrew I will also look at the IO.Path.Combine